# Post per label hidden/limit Blogger

Tags: blogs, blogger

I have a blog C# tutorial. When i want to show post with specific label I found that some of my post was hidden.

Example: When i want to show post with label "Lập trình C#", i have this link: http://iceteaviet.blogspot.com/search/label/C%23%20Winform%20c%C4%83n%20b%E1%BA%A3n

I have exactly **13** post with this label, but the number of post showed here is only **10**, and there is **only 1 page**. 
I have the same problem with all others label, while there is 8 - 10 post showed in the first page, and there is NOT the second page.

This is my xml (too long to show here): `pastebin.com/Te12Lpee`

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As your label shows some blank spaces that will convert them into `%20`. This will impact as negative SEO technique on search engines.

You're required to put dashes (-) between each word. for example

```
http://iceteaviet.blogspot.com/search/label/C%23%20Winform%20c%C4%83n%20b%E1%BA%A3n
```

shall be as

```
http://iceteaviet.blogspot.com/search/label/C#-Winform-căn-bản
```

or

```
http://iceteaviet.blogspot.com/search/label/C-#-Winform-Basic
```

2. You may try to fix number of posts per label that will surely solve your problem. Just use `?&max-results=6` after each label with going in blogger template section.

Comment: Thanks!
I fix my number of posts per label.

But the 1st thing you said, if i want to put dashes between each word in the search/label/ link, i must change my label name, so it looks not very friendly.

Is there another way?

Comment: This is a necessary because these labels are not user friendly nor search engine friendly. Now I'll tell that how to do this:
Go to blogger post section > Select anyone post > Click on Label Icon (Just located with publish and revert to draft buttons) > Click New Label > Type C-#-Winform-Basic (or any) > Click OK
See image (http://prntscr.com/9g2r21)